# Apache Camel JPA: Connect to two database instances

Tags: apache, jpa

Is there an obvious way to use two JPA consumers/producers in the Camel Spring DSL to talk to two different database instances? I tried to configure two EntityManagerFactory instances pointing to  two Persistence Units but end up with the following when error :(

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: Found 2 beans of type: interface javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory. Only one bean expected.
```

Camel Version: 2.13.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to make 2 entity manager factories, and have them point at different persistence units.

```
   <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="primary" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory2"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="secondary" />
    </bean>
```

then when you set up the jpa bean, you can specify two different origins

```
<bean id="jpa" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpa2" class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory2" />
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
</bean>
```

and use:

```
<from uri="jpa://
```

or

```
<from uri="jpa2://
```

Comment: Yeah, I did try that option expecting it to work, however, that's when I encountered the above error. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The answer you mentioned works correctly. I messed up  using the org.apache.camel.BeanInject annotation while looking up the EntityManagerFactory in my test class. This caused it to look for a unique reference to the EntityManagerFactory. Your answer is perfectly correct, two JPA consumers work alongside very well . Thanks again.